# htaccess mod-rewrite rule for query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say the querystring is something like this

```
file.php?x=abc&y=a-b&z=ab-3
```

I want the output as

```
file/abc/a-b/ab-3
```

how would i accomplish this?

I am using this:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(.*)$ file.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [NC,L]
```

It is doing fine unless I dont use dashes "-" between the values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ file.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```